# What is the first movie where the voice of the receiving person can be heard in phone conversations?

Tags: first-appearance

In classic movies, they simply mute the receiving person's voice in phone conservation scenes.

So what is the first movie where we hear the receiver's voice in the phone conversation?

Comment: What do you mean? In "classic" movies they usually show the other end of the conversation, too, if it's important. Sometimes with a split-screen. So what exactly are you looking for? Is it that, or only when the voice is actually heard "through the phone" in the same scene?